# Need help with calculating a date that only falls on a weekday

Tags: office-365, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, date

I have a column named "Date received" and I need to calculate a "Date Due".

The due date is 3 calendar days after received however if that falls on a weekend it needs to be the next business day. I've been messing with this way too long and can't get it to work.   I can get it in excel but not sharepoint.

my eq in excel was `=IF(OR(WEEKDAY(D7+3)=7,WEEKDAY(D7+3)=1),WORKDAY(D7+3,1),D7+3)`

```
D7=[date received]
```

I'm using SharePoint Online (Office 365).

Any help would be great

Answer (score 3):

https://www.365csi.nl/vm365com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List

The WORKDAY function does not exist in SharePoint

the WEEKDAY( date , [format] ) function returns the daynumber,
where sunday=1 with the default non-specified format

```
        WEEKDAY daystoadd   
sunday  : 1      3
monday  : 2      3
tuesday : 3      3
wednesday 4      5
thursday: 5      4
friday  : 6      3
saturday: 7      3
```

That makes your Formula:

```
= D7 + CHOOSE( WEEKDAY(D7) , 3 , 3 , 3 , 5 , 4 , 3 , 3 )
```